# Шифрование закрытым ключом или ЭЦП

Tags: python, rsa, цифровая-подпись

Уже запутался...

Если я хочу подписать какие-то данные, я использую ассиметричное шифрование.

То есть обычное ассиметричное шифрование происходит так: `шифруется открытым и расшифровывается закрытым ключом`. А при подписи наоборот — `шифруется закрытым и расшифровывается открытым ключом`

Получается, я для таких целей могу использовать `RSA`? Как я понял, в `RSA` нет разницы какой именно ключ будет использовать для шифрования, а какой для расшифровки.

Я использовал библиотеку `rsa` в питоне, для того, чтобы сделать подпись, но он не хочет расшифровывать данные используя публичный ключ.

Подскажите как правильно использовать RSA для цифровой подписи

Comment: В библиотеке [cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/) вроде всё нужное должно быть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Электронная подпись создается следующим образом:

1. *(Дополнительный шаг) Документ сжимают каким-нибудь алгоритмом (zip)*
2. Вычисляют криптографически-стойкую (это очень важно) хеш-сумму документа
3. Из суммы и других мета-данных (дата подписания, имя подписанта и пр.) формируют открытый текст
4. Открытый текст шифруют закрытым (private) ключом и получается подпись
5. Документ и подпись передают третим лицам

Для проверки подобной подписи нужно сделать следующее:

1. Подпись дешифруют публичным (public) ключом подписанта и получают открытый текст с хэш-суммой и мета-данными
2. *(Дополнительный шаг) Документ сжимают*
3. Вычисляют хеш-сумму документа
4. Сумму полученную из подписи и из предыдущего пункта сравнивают, если они равны, то подпись верна
5. Проверяют мета-данные

В библиотеке [rsa](https://github.com/sybrenstuvel/python-rsa/) уже есть методы для создания и проверки цифровой подписи.

Создают её так

```
(pubkey, privkey) = rsa.newkeys(512)
message = 'Go left at the blue tree'
signature = rsa.sign(message, privkey, 'SHA-1')
```

Проверяют так

```
message = 'Go left at the blue tree'
rsa.verify(message, signature, pubkey)
```